# Elegant time print in C++11

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11, time

This is what I'd like to do in C++11: given two time points (such as a timing class) as `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`, print their time difference elegantly, for instance:

```
1 day 4 hours 3 minutes 45 seconds
```

or

```
32 minutes 54 seconds 345 milliseconds
```

Please note that I'm not interested in simply using `put_time`, since I want to print starting from *the most significant unit* of time. I know, it's a solution to just print the difference, but it's not pretty: I'm looking for an *elegant* solution :)

Cheers!

Comment: What solution do you have right now?

Comment: Using a custom `put_time` formatting, based on a subsequent division by days, hours, ..., kinda like @Simple wrote. But I'm hoping to find something prettier! :)

Comment: @senseiwa I don't get it. *" I'm not interested in simply using put_time, since I want to print starting from the most significant unit of time."* Why can't you use `put_time` to start from the most significant unit of time? I am afraid I am missing a point.

Comment: Because I'd like to generalize the printing, and though it is weird, I'd like to avoid subsequent subtractions in order to find the most significant unit that is non zero.

Answer (score 7):

Duration can do arithmetic.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main(){
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using day_t = duration<long, std::ratio<3600 * 24>>;
    auto start = system_clock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));
    auto end = system_clock::now();
    auto dur = end - start;
    auto d = duration_cast<day_t>(dur);
    auto h = duration_cast<hours>(dur -= d);
    auto m = duration_cast<minutes>(dur -= h);
    auto s = duration_cast<seconds>(dur -= m);
    auto ms = duration_cast<seconds>(dur -= s);
    std::cout << d.count() << " days, "
        << h.count() << " hours, "
        << m.count() << " minutes, "
        << s.count() << " seconds, "
        << ms.count() << " milliseconds\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Possible duplicate: [Extract year/month/day etc. from std::chrono::time_point in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957805/extract-year-month-day-etc-from-stdchronotime-point-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easily extensible solution using variadic templates and recursion. It defines `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const duration&)` for ease of use.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using day_t = std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<3600 * 24>>;

template<typename> struct duration_traits {};

#define DURATION_TRAITS(Duration, Singular, Plural) \
template<> struct duration_traits<Duration> { \
    constexpr static const char* singular = Singular; \
    constexpr static const char* plural = Plural; \
}

DURATION_TRAITS(std::chrono::milliseconds, "millisecond", "milliseconds");
DURATION_TRAITS(std::chrono::seconds, "second", "seconds");
DURATION_TRAITS(std::chrono::minutes, "minute", "minutes");
DURATION_TRAITS(std::chrono::hours, "hour", "hours");
DURATION_TRAITS(day_t, "day", "days");

using divisions = std::tuple<std::chrono::milliseconds, 
                             std::chrono::seconds, 
                             std::chrono::minutes, 
                             std::chrono::hours, 
                             day_t>;

namespace detail {
template<typename...> struct print_duration_impl_ {};

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct print_duration_impl_<Head, Tail...> {
    template <typename Duration>
    static bool print(std::ostream& os, Duration& dur) {
        const auto started_printing = print_duration_impl_<Tail...>::print(os, dur);

        const auto n = std::chrono::duration_cast<Head>(dur);
        const auto count = n.count();

        if (count == 0) {
            return started_printing;
        }

        if (started_printing) {
            os << ' ';
        }

        using traits = duration_traits<Head>;
        os << count << ' ' << (count == 1 ? traits::singular : traits::plural);
        dur -= n;

        return true;
    }
};

template<>
struct print_duration_impl_<> {
    template <typename Duration>
    static bool print(std::ostream& os, Duration& dur) {
        return false;
    }
};

template<typename...> struct print_duration {};

template<typename... Args>
struct print_duration<std::tuple<Args...>> {
    template<typename Duration>
    static void print(std::ostream& os, Duration dur) {
        print_duration_impl_<Args...>::print(os, dur);
    }
};
}

template<typename Rep, typename Period>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& dur) {
    detail::print_duration<divisions>::print(os, dur);
    return os;
}
```

New durations are added by specializing `duration_traits` and inserting the type at the correct position in divisions. For example, adding a 10 ms jiffy type would involve:

```
using jiffy_t = std::chrono::duration<long long, std::centi>;
DURATION_TRAITS(jiffy_t, "jiffy", "jiffies");

using divisions = std::tuple<std::chrono::milliseconds, 
                             jiffy_t,
                             std::chrono::seconds, 
                             std::chrono::minutes, 
                             std::chrono::hours, 
                             day_t>;
```

Not bad for three lines of code!

Live example on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/aVqyR3).

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T>
void print_time_diff(std::ostream& out, T prior, T latter)
{
    namespace sc = std::chrono;
    auto diff = sc::duration_cast<sc::milliseconds>(latter - prior).count();
    auto const msecs = diff % 1000;
    diff /= 1000;
    auto const secs = diff % 60;
    diff /= 60;
    auto const mins = diff % 60;
    diff /= 60;
    auto const hours = diff % 24;
    diff /= 24;
    auto const days = diff;

    bool printed_earlier = false;
    if (days >= 1) {
        printed_earlier = true;
        out << days << (1 != days ? " days" : " day") << ' ';
    }
    if (printed_earlier || hours >= 1) {
        printed_earlier = true;
        out << hours << (1 != hours ? " hours" : " hour") << ' ';
    }
    if (printed_earlier || mins >= 1) {
        printed_earlier = true;
        out << mins << (1 != mins ? " minutes" : " minute") << ' ';
    }
    if (printed_earlier || secs >= 1) {
        printed_earlier = true;
        out << secs << (1 != secs ? " seconds" : " second") << ' ';
    }
    if (printed_earlier || msecs >= 1) {
        printed_earlier = true;
        out << msecs << (1 != msecs ? " milliseconds" : " millisecond");
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/bBNHQp

Comment: Thanks, this is very similar to the solution I'm using right now. I was wondering if there is a more coincise way of expressing divisions. For instance, printing file sizes is quite coincise by using `log10` and finding the maximum unit of measure. I don't know if there is a clever way of transposing this to time...