# How do you print the current system time with milliseconds in C++11?

Tags: c++, date, c++11, time, c++-chrono

I've got a problem with getting actual system time with milliseconds. The only one good method I found is in `Windows.h`, but I can't use it. I'm supposed to use `std::chrono`. How can I do this?

I spent a lot of time trying to google it, but I found only second-precision examples.

I'm trying to get string like this:

```
[2014-11-25 22:15:38:449]
```

Comment: There is no standard way to print date with milliseconds. Using `std::chrono` I think all you can do is converting a `time_point` on your own.

Comment: You will need to use platform specific calls to get millisecond accuracy.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm pretty sure that chrono can pull an accuracy of up to a few microseconds, if the system allows it. For example try running this code: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15958113/365496):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Duration>
void print_time(tm t, Duration fraction) {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::printf("[%04u-%02u-%02u %02u:%02u:%02u.%03u]\n", t.tm_year + 1900,
                t.tm_mon + 1, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec,
                static_cast<unsigned>(fraction / milliseconds(1)));

    // VS2013's library has a bug which may require you to replace
    // "fraction / milliseconds(1)" with
    // "duration_cast<milliseconds>(fraction).count()"
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
    system_clock::duration tp = now.time_since_epoch();

    tp -= duration_cast<seconds>(tp);

    time_t tt = system_clock::to_time_t(now);

    print_time(*gmtime(&tt), tp);
    print_time(*localtime(&tt), tp);
}
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the fact that the timer returns values of sub-millisecond denominations does not necessarily indicate that the timer has sub-millisecond resolution. I think Windows' implementation in VS2015 may finally be fixed, but the timer they've been using to back their chrono implementation so far has been sensitive to the OS [`timeBeginPeriod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) setting, displaying varying resolution, and the default setting is I think 16 milliseconds.

Also the above code assumes that neither UTC nor your local timezone are offset from the epoch of `std::chrono::system_clock` by a fractional second value.

---

Example of using Howard's date functions to avoid ctime: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98db840b238d3ce7

Comment: You only need to subtract the seconds from tp because it converts the duration in second, however many they might be. Only `seconds s = duration_cast<seconds>(tp);  tp -= s;`

Comment: That's true, the other values are only used in the 'debug' code for displaying the full duration.

Comment: And if you don't want to trudge through the C API you can do something like this: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#What%20can%20I%20do%20with%20that%20<code>chrono</code>%20compatibility?

Comment: I was pulling together a work-around like this and saw "If std::time_t has lower precision, it is implementation-defined whether the value is rounded or truncated".  That implies that we don't know if we can just add the milliseconds because the seconds out of to_time_t() may be one tick higher.  Am I right about that?

Comment: @JayMiller Yeah, that's true. I'm not certain what most implementations do. You may want to just go ahead and use Howard's date functions to replace `to_time_t()` yourself.

Comment: The `%03u` conversion assumes the `duration<...>::rep` is 32-bit. Another way to do it is `std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.")
    << std::setprecision(3) << std::setfill('0')
    << fraction / milliseconds(1)
    << "]\n";`

Comment: @JonathanWakely True, and the spec actually requires more bits for `std::chrono::milliseconds`. I'm actually relying on printf format checking to catch that, which unfortunately VS doesn't yet provide (except in their static analysis tool I think). You can see in my second example where I caught this thanks to compiler warnings. I've fixed the first example now.

Answer (score 4):

This answer still uses a bit of C API but is only used in the function, so you can forget about it:

```
template<typename T>
void print_time(std::chrono::time_point<T> time) {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    time_t curr_time = T::to_time_t(time);
    char sRep[100];
    strftime(sRep,sizeof(sRep),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",localtime(&curr_time));

    typename T::duration since_epoch = time.time_since_epoch();
    seconds s = duration_cast<seconds>(since_epoch);
    since_epoch -= s;
    milliseconds milli = duration_cast<milliseconds>(since_epoch);

    cout << '[' << sRep << ":" << milli.count() << "]\n";
}
```

This is merely a rewrite of the code that bames53, but using strftime to shorten the code a bit.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `strftime` is not available on Windows.

Comment: Since `strftime` is part of the C++ standard (in `ctime`), I suspect it *is* available in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`std::chrono` give you utilities to represent a point in time or the elapsed duration between two points in time.  It allows you to get information about these time intervals.

It does *not* provide any *calendar* information. Unfortunately, at this time there are no tools in the C++ standard for these.  `boost::date_time` may be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Did anybody notice that to_time_t rounds the seconds, instead of truncating

```
auto now = system_clock::now();
time_t secs = system_clock::to_time_t(now);
now {_MyDur={_MyRep=15107091978759765 } }
secs = 1510709198
```

so when you tack on the milliseconds

```
auto tse = now.time_since_epoch();
auto now_ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(tse);
auto now_s = duration_cast<seconds>(tse);
auto jst_ms = now_ms - now_s;
DWORD msecs = jst_ms.count();
msecs = 875
```

secs should be 1510709197, but look at now_s, it's right

```
now_s {_MyRep=1510709197 }
```