# Print current system time in nanoseconds using c++ chrono

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I print the current time using the `std::chrono` library?

I would like the format to be: `hour:minute:second:millisecond:microsecond:nanosecond`.

Comment: Does your OS support nanosecond resolution?

Comment: If not nano second, may i know how to get till micro or atleast millisecond in above format.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time

Comment: I dont think put_time is giving option for millisecond. Or, does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. My mistake.

Comment: @user3665224 _"I dont think put_time is giving option for millisecond."_ There's an option to print seconds fraction though.

Comment: I want to register my system time at a particular moment with milliseconds or microseconds precision. May i know how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "register"? Do you want to print it on screen of "register" it?

Comment: Both to print and store in a variable

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136854/c11-actual-system-time-with-milliseconds/27137877#27137877

Comment: Helpful code and algorithms on this subject are here: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html  Specifically see "What can I do with that chrono compatibility?"

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Please remove "on hold" status from this post as this question is answered correctly below

Comment: @user3665224: Whether a question has an answer has nothing to do with whether it should be re-opened. And, it already has four reopen votes: the first one was mine. Thanks for playing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

Changing the code to C++ style:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();

typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio_multiply<std::chrono::hours::period, std::ratio<8>
>::type> Days; /* UTC: +8:00 */

Days days = std::chrono::duration_cast<Days>(duration);
    duration -= days;
auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(duration);
    duration -= hours;
auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(duration);
    duration -= minutes;
auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(duration);
    duration -= seconds;
auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration);
    duration -= milliseconds;
auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration);
    duration -= microseconds;
auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration);

std::cout << hours.count() << ":"
          << minutes.count() << ":"
          << seconds.count() << ":"
          << milliseconds.count() << ":"
          << microseconds.count() << ":"
          << nanoseconds.count() << std::endl;
```

Result:

```
17:56:14:94:451:679
```

**[Old]**

A simply example:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

char fmt[64];
char buf[64];
struct timeval tv;
struct tm *tm;

gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
tm = localtime (&tv.tv_sec);
strftime (fmt, sizeof (fmt), "%H:%M:%S:%%06u", tm);
snprintf (buf, sizeof (buf), fmt, tv.tv_usec);
printf ("%s\n", buf);
```

Result:

```
00:01:32:695240
```

Comment: Thank you. But, may i please know what is %%06u. Is it possible to get microseconds in same format?

Comment: —1: Where is the `std::chrono` usage here? This is some C nonsense from 120 years ago!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks, the code is really old. I wrote it few years ago. I already modified the code into new C++11 style.

Comment: You don't like C++ very much, do you? :) +1

Comment: Right, I usually write C/script language to solve system problem.

Comment: Ok this is much better now. You should explain how displaying nanoseconds places doesn't actually mean the clock has nanosecond accuracy (it almost certainly does not), so many of these digits will be completely meaningless.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because in OS, time is maintained by `struct timeval` which only consist seconds(tv_sec) and microseconds(tv_usec). Consequently, it means nanoseconds in a high-level language level is totally meaningless.

Comment: Can you please confirm if "17:56:14:94:451:679" is the local system time? When i run the same code, I get some time but that is not my system time. For instance, my local time is 00:25:9:40:240:900 (approx time). But this program gives 18:55:9:40:830:845

Comment: @user3665224 `time_point` will return the value from (1970.01.01 00:00:00 UTC) to present. To be human-readable, value should minus  (Today 00:00 UTC). You need to manipulate it by yourself, because I don't know your UTC time.

Comment: @KirChou: Um, yes, _I_ know that. What I meant was, you should add this into the answer because at the moment the answer doesn't even briefly mention it.

Comment: @KirChou: Those two timestamps are blatantly not offset by any known national timezone.

Comment: so 20 lines of code and dozen allocations is now preferred solution to 4 lines of code because its `old` ? good to know