# How to store, print and parse date time as yyyyMMdd-HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn C++

Tags: c++, timestamp, c++20, c++-chrono

I faced with problem of correct way to store and work with date and time by specific locale or stamp including nanoseconds: `yyyyMMdd-HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn` (example: 20211215-06:36:01.571670316).

**Option 1**
I need to store the date time including nanoseconds so I found few examples with `std::chrono::nanoseconds`. As I understand it is a period from 1970 (`std::chrono::duration`) and I can take days, hours, minuts etc. include nanoseconds (got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677964/print-current-system-time-in-nanoseconds-using-c-chrono))

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto duration = now.time_since_epoch();
typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio_multiply<std::chrono::hours::period, std::ratio<8>>::type> Days; // UTC: +8:00
Days days = std::chrono::duration_cast<Days>(duration);
duration -= days;
auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(duration);
duration -= hours;
auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(duration);
duration -= minutes;
auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(duration);
duration -= seconds;
auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration);
duration -= milliseconds;
auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration);
duration -= microseconds;
auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(duration);
std::cout << hours.count() << ":"
<< minutes.count() << ":"
<< seconds.count() << "."
<< milliseconds.count()
<< microseconds.count()
<< nanoseconds.count() << std::endl;
```

**Question 1.1**: How can I print this stored date time `std::chrono::duration` as `std::string` or `char*` using locale or stamp `yyyyMMdd-HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn`?

**Question 1.2** How can I parse `std::string` or `char*` with same locale or stamp as `std::chrono::duration` to save it?

**Question 1.3** Are there any other ways to use `std::chrono::duration`  for date time store, print and parce as I need?

---

**Option 2**

I also tried to use next approach (got [here](https://gist.github.com/dtoma/cc3d5b2dd4c03a25886adededcc1e3b9)). Here the date and time use one source it's `std::chrono::time_point`, the nanoseconds added as additional part by cast to the `std::chrono::duration`:

```
std::chrono::time_point now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
auto tm = *std::gmtime(&time);

auto epoch = now.time_since_epoch();
auto ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(epoch).count() % 1000000000;

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y%m%d-%T.");
auto str = oss.str();

std::cout << str << ns ;
```

out: `20220110-04:00:25.576973219`

As I see everything looks good, we use only std::chrono::time_point to store date and time, but I don't really think it's good way to use lot of additional casts, like `std::chrono::duration` for nanoseconds and `std::ostringstream` to string.

So then I have another questions:

**Question 2.1** Is it a good way to store print and parse date time or I can do it witout lot of cast?

**Question 2.2** What is the correct approach to get `std::chrono::time_point` from `std::string` or `char*` using locale or stamp `yyyyMMdd-HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn`?

Unfortunately c++20 `std::format` doesn't work with gcc

**Additional information:**

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.3
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
```

BTW Clion write cmake version is 3.21.1

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is tagged C++20, I'm going to show a C++20 solution, even though your compiler does not yet implement these parts of C++20.  However, there exists a [free, open-source, header-only preview](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) of this part of C++20 that you can use in the interim which gives you a very nice migration path to C++20.  Additionally the C++20 tools in this area are far easier to use than in prior C++ standards.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    stringstream io;
    sys_time<nanoseconds> now = system_clock::now();
    io << format("{:%Y%m%d-%T}", now);  // store
    cout << io.str() << '\n';           // 20220110-15:13:19.576742000
    now = {};                           // "zero out" now just to tell if the parse works
    io >> parse("%Y%m%d-%T", now);      // parse
    assert(!io.fail());                 // another way to tell if the parse works
    cout << now << '\n';                // 2022-01-10 15:13:19.576742000
}
```

- No casts
- Simple
- nanosecond precision
- Note that this is a UTC timestamp
- On gcc, you could use `auto` in place of `sys_time<nanoseconds>`, but this makes the precision platform-dependent.  E.g. macOS would give you microseconds.

To use the [free, open-source, header-only preview](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

- Replace `#include <format>` with `#include "date/date.h"`.
- Add `using namespace date;`
- Change the first format string from `"{:%Y%m%d-%T}"` to `"%Y%m%d-%T"`

Comment: thank you! It looks really intersting for me, but at this project stage I looking for light, standart solutions without any extentions to external libs. It would great if the std::format work in current gcc version, but it's not =(

Comment: Why does the `format` function work fine with `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` but does not work with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` aka `steady_clock`?

Comment: Because `steady_clock` has no relationship to the calendar, much like a stop watch.  The best you can do is stream out `steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()`.