# how to create time stamp with microsecond

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm trying to generate a timestamp with a resolution of a microsecond. 
I tried using  this answer  [Extract year/month/day etc. from std::chrono::time_point in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957805/extract-year-month-day-etc-from-stdchronotime-point-in-c/15958113#15958113) and also this one: [C++11 actual system time with milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136854/c11-actual-system-time-with-milliseconds/57942599#57942599)
but I'm not sure that doing it right:

```
template <typename Duration>
void print_time(tm t, Duration fraction) {
using namespace std::chrono;
std::printf("[%04u-%02u-%02u %02u:%02u:%02u.%03u.%03u]\n", t.tm_year + 1900,
        t.tm_mon + 1, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec,
        static_cast<unsigned>(fraction / milliseconds(1)),
        static_cast<unsigned>(fraction / microseconds(1)));
}

int main() {
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
system_clock::duration tp = now.time_since_epoch();
tp -= duration_cast<seconds>(tp);
time_t tt = system_clock::to_time_t(now);
cout << tp.count() <<endl;
print_time(*gmtime(&tt), tp);
print_time(*localtime(&tt), tp);
```

and the output for this code is :

> 324760155 
>   [2019-09-15 10:09:13.324.324760]
>   [2019-09-15 10:09:13.324.324760]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename Rep, typename Period>
void
print_time(tm t, std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> fraction)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(fraction);
    fraction -= ms;
    auto us = duration_cast<microseconds>(fraction);
    std::printf("[%04u-%02u-%02u %02u:%02u:%02u.%03u.%03u]\n", t.tm_year + 1900,
        t.tm_mon + 1, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec,
        static_cast<unsigned>(ms / milliseconds(1)),
        static_cast<unsigned>(us / microseconds(1)));
}
```

- The change I made to your parameter keeps it from being overly generic and accepting something that is not a `chrono::duration`.
- To get the number of `milliseconds` out of `fraction` (and assuming `fraction` is non-negative), just `duration_cast<milliseconds>(fraction)`.
- Now you need to subtract the `milliseconds` obtained in the previous step *out* of `fraction`, lest they will come back to haunt you in the next step.
- To get the number of `microseconds` out of `fraction` (and assuming `fraction` is non-negative), just `duration_cast<microseconds>(fraction)`.

If you wanted to go further and get the `nanoseconds` out of `fraction`, you would need to first subtract the `microseconds` part out before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

You are losing accuracy on this line:
`tp -= duration_cast<seconds>(tp);`
 Get data in microseconds at once, and better in nanoseconds, and then re-read them in the desired format.

Comment: now I'm getting 
[2019-09-15 10:46:00.881297578.829282533]  what the mining of these numbers?

Comment: this time in nanoseconds from January 1, 1970 to the current moment. i.e. UNIX time. But divided by millisecond (first number) and microsecond (second). The question is, what do you think should have been in the last numbers? Because if we needed a timestamp in seconds / milliseconds / microseconds / nanoseconds just like unix time? which can then be converted into a readable time by a standard function. What is written at the end of printf is superfluous, it was enough to get tp in the right format and that's it.

Comment: my main goal is to measure to benchmark my program by comparing timestamp, so I want  the time stamp to be like
HH:MM:SS:ML:US

Comment: We will go the other way:<br>    ```std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
std::chrono::system_clock::duration elapsed;
start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
/*main programm cicle*/
elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start); //now we have the number of microseconds spent```    <br>   Name the number of microseconds, we can divide them by the number of microseconds per hour, get hours / in a minute - get minutes / in a second. You just need to remember to subtract the result already obtained.