# How can my C++ program access the computer's date and time to print and use just the current year?

Tags: c++

Consider this program written in pseudocode:

```
//Tell program to access the system's date and time

//print just the 'current year', without having to print the entire time,date format.

//Be able to perform calculations with the printed number (for example: 2019), without having to manually enter it anywhere.
```

My goal is to figure out how to access just a single information like date, month or year and make it a usable operand inside the program to perform operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract year/month/day etc. from std::chrono::time\_point in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957805/extract-year-month-day-etc-from-stdchronotime-point-in-c)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c

Comment: @uneven_mark Yes it does! Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
    std::cout << "Year = " << 1900 + ltm->tm_year << std::endl;
}
```

See documentation for [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/).