# How c++ stores the current month name?

Tags: c++, datetime

I wrote a code to generate the current date and time..
and I got the following result

Wed May 27 21:02:48 2020

I want to create an array of months and compare the months

```
string months[12] ={ "January", "February", "March", etc"};
string months[12] ={ "Jan","Feb","Mar",etc};
```

which one can I use so that it match with the c++ month format?

Comment: How did you produce the above date-time string (the one you want to compare against)?  As you can see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time  it can be rather flexible.

Comment: ```
time_t now = time(0);
char* dt = ctime(&now);
cout << "date and time is " << dt << endl;
```

Comment: If I'm right, you wants to compare the month string returned by the system with your given month, it's a bit tough though. [Extracting year/month/day with std::chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15958113/11471113). Look at the answer's **Update** section. There you can find your solution.