# C++ 20 local_time components to zoned_time and time span between two local times

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I'd like to manipulate local time dates and then compute the time span between them. Questions:

- what is the best way to go from a zoned_time to his components (y,m,d,hh,mm,ss, etc...) and back (taking into account dst)?
- what is the correct way to find the elapsing time between two zoned_times?

What I tried so far:

I found that I can get the now from clock and then compute a zoned_time. Manipulating this info is becoming a nightmare though.

I found on this answer that, [Extract year/month/day etc. from std::chrono::time_point in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957805/extract-year-month-day-etc-from-stdchronotime-point-in-c)

```
#include <chrono>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto tp = zoned_time{current_zone(), system_clock::now()}.get_local_time();
    auto dp = floor<days>(tp);
    year_month_day ymd{dp};
    hh_mm_ss time{floor<milliseconds>(tp-dp)};
    auto y = ymd.year();
    auto m = ymd.month();
    auto d = ymd.day();
    auto h = time.hours();
    auto M = time.minutes();
    auto s = time.seconds();
    auto ms = time.subseconds();
}
```

this would allow for example to take the current date, and be able to set for example:

```
h = 5;
M = 0;
s = 0;
ms = 0;
```

and have the 5am of the current date, but how to convert this information back into a zoned_time? Obviously this doesn't work:

```
auto rec = zoned_time(current_zone(), y + m + d + h + M + s + ms);
```

This seems a good approximation:

```
auto rec = zoned_time(current_zone(), std::chrono::local_days{y / m / d} + h + M + s + ms);

if (tp_s == rec) std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
else {
    std::cout << "different" << std::endl;
    std::cout << tp  << "\t" << rec << std::endl;
}
```

but it prints:

> different
> 2023-03-21 10:54:30.0128147     2023-03-21 10:54:30.012 GMT

aside the small difference in time, what is perplexing is the `std::chrono::local_days{y / m / d} + h + M + s + ms`. It's not really clear if the addition means shifting by a time interval or setting the actual fields. It's quite different to add 5h if there is a DST in the middle, or setting the hours field to 5.

Finally, I'd like to find the true time interval between the two local times, and i think it's done by:

```
auto diff = duration_cast<chr::minutes>(tp_s.get_sys_time() - rec.get_sys_time());
```

so this should return the true time passed between the two points regardless the DST, while
i'm not really understanding what this really represents:

```
auto diff = duration_cast<chr::minutes>(tp_s.get_local_time() - rec.get_local_time());
```

Comment: Please in first paragraph explain exactly what are you trying to calculate. You are to focus on explaining what have you tried and it is hard to tell if this is good approach without understanding actual goal. `I'd like to manipulate local time dates and then compute the time span between them.` is to general and to vague. Also please provide [mcve], your code is to much sliced to compose something which I could verify. Test (failing) [would be great](https://godbolt.org/z/Kdhd8e8qc).

Comment: Hi Marek, my starting problem is: given 3 daily shifts, 5am to 1pm, 1pm to 9pm, 9pm to 5am, find all the starting point and duration of the shifts between an startTime and an endTime. startTime and endTime are given in minutes from now. It should take into account DST. The starting point and duration are in minutes from now. I haven't written the code yet cause it's difficult to understand how to manipulate local dates for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - what is the best way to go from a zoned_time to his components (y,m,d,hh,mm,ss, etc...) and back (taking into account dst)?

You've done it right, except that you go too far.  A good rule of thumb in chrono is:

- Minimize escaping the type safety of chrono types.

This means try not to convert to integral types.

```
auto zt = zoned_time{current_zone(), system_clock::now()};
auto tp = zt.get_local_time();
auto dp = floor<days>(tp);
year_month_day ymd{dp};
hh_mm_ss time{floor<milliseconds>(tp-dp)};
```

You now have one structure that holds the local `{y, m, d}` and another structure that holds the local `{hh, mm, ss, subseconds}`.  And as you've seen there are getters on each of those fields, and if you really have to you can turn those results into integral values, but don't.

Now if you want to turn this into local 05:00:00 of that day, it is simply:

```
tp = dp + 5h;
```

Or if you prefer:

```
tp = local_days{ymd} + 5h;
```

To get it back into the `zoned_time`:

```
zt = tp;
```

Note that an important difference between this and calling `current_zone()` again is that each call to `current_zone()` looks up the current `current_zone()`.  If you're worried about mobile devices, keep in mind that the return of `current_zone()` can change at any time.  And if you want to ensure that you get the same value during a computation, only call it once.

> different 2023-03-21 10:54:30.0128147 2023-03-21 10:54:30.012 GMT

This is because `tp` has type `local_time<decimicroseconds>` (the native precision of your `system_clock` on Windows) and `rec` has precision `milliseconds` given from this line:

```
hh_mm_ss time{floor<milliseconds>(tp-dp)};
```

Without the `floor<milliseconds>` this would've yielded the native `system_clock` precision.

In the local time addition:

```
tp = local_days{ymd} + 5h;
```

there is no implicit shifting under the hood.  This is just straight forward arithmetic under the hood.  It adds the number of days since 1970-01-01 to 5 hours, taking care of the conversion of days to hours under the hood.  This is exactly the same arithmetic as if you had used `sys_days` and done the arithmetic in Unix Time.

The UTC offset comes into play when you assign this back to a `zoned_time`:

```
zt = tp;
```

The assignment recognizes the `local_time` type and thus knows how to apply the UTC offset to get `sys_time` (and vice-versa when assigned from `sys_time`).

Also note that at this point in the computation, there are no longer any fields.  Once you move away from `year_month_day` and `hh_mm_ss`, you are dealing in chronological types represented by a single value under the hood (count of ticks since the epoch).

> Finally, I'd like to find the true time interval between the two local times, and i think it's done by:

```
auto diff = duration_cast<chr::minutes>(tp_s.get_sys_time() - rec.get_sys_time());
```

That is exactly correct.  If there is a UTC offset change between these two instants, that change will be correctly accounted for.

> while i'm not really understanding what this really represents:

```
auto diff = duration_cast<chr::minutes>(tp_s.get_local_time() - rec.get_local_time());
```

This is called "local time arithmetic" and is useful when you want to "preserve" parts of the local time throughout the arithmetic, effectively ignoring UTC offset changes.

A classic example is:  I want to have a meeting at 9am local time every morning.  This morning's meeting is at:

```
zoned_time zt{current_zone(), local_days{2023y/March/21} + 9h};
```

Tomorrow's meeting is at:

```
zt = zt.get_local_time() + days{1};
```

Remember, there are no fields here.  Just a count of ticks from the epoch.  You add exactly 1 day (24 hours, or 86400 seconds) to the *local time*.  This will get you 9am tomorrow, *whether or not* there is a UTC offset change tonight.

If there *is* a UTC offset change between today and tomorrow, then if you retrieved the `sys_time` before and after the addition of `days{1}`, then that difference would not be equal to `days{1}`.

And if you wanted the next meeting to be exactly 24 hours later in physical time, one would do the arithmetic in `sys_time` instead of in `local_time`.