# Don't understand tm_struct (C++) calculations - is there an offset of some kind?

Tags: c++, date, datetime

I can't understand why the `tm` struct in C++ behaves this way. Let me be more specific - if I were to get the current time, I'd probably do something like this

```
time_t now = time(0);
tm *nowTm = gmtime(&now);
```

And upon printing out the date, I expect something like `2015/06/13` (the current date as of this post)

```
cout << nowTm->tm_year << "/" << nowTm->tm_mon << "/" << nowTm->tm_mday;
```

But instead, I find out that it prints out `1150/5/13` instead. For the month value, I simply added 1 to set it to the correct month, but playing around with the year proved troublesome.

I came across this SO post: [Algorithm to add or subtract days from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344330/algorithm-to-add-or-subtract-days-from-a-date), which said to subtract 1900 from the year to get the correct year. I tried that to no avail.

I then tried adding on the difference between the current year and 1150, `2015 - 1150 = 865` to get the correct year, but it gave me `9800` instead of `2015`.

I then experimented with adding for the year, and found that

1. If I +1 to the year, it goes up in increments of 10 years.
2. If I +0.1 to the year, it would divide the date by zero and add 0.1 to it (e.g. 1150 + 1 = 115.01).

I'm confused - why does this happen and how do I get the correct year in my `tm` struct?

Comment: You probably want to use "tm_mday" for the month, not "tm_mon"

Comment: @TrevorHickey, `tm_mday` is the day of the month.

Comment: Also, you would add 1900; not subtract.  "nowTm->tm_year+1900"

Comment: Are you sure it prints `1150` and not `115`? Because `115` would be the correct value I'd expect.

Comment: @TrevorHickey I tried adding 1900 as well to no avail - it outputted 20150. I then tried dividing that by 0, but it gave 2010 instead of 2015...

Comment: It prints `115`. http://ideone.com/Yufvk4 OP just needs to read the fine manual. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Comment: Works ok for me. See http://ideone.com/F01Sb9.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: looks like you need to read the doc, too. `nowTm->tm_mon` needs to be `nowTm->tm_mon + 1`.

Comment: @CodeApprentice, Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that outputs what you claim.

Comment: Oh goodness I'm embarrassed...I outputted an extra 0 at the end and forgot to comment that line of code - silly me! Thank you for all your patience and explanations - I'll be more careful in the future! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation on `tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) we can see that:

- `tm_year` is years since 1900, not the current year number, i.e. it should be 115 this year.
- `tm_mon` is months since January (range 0-11), not the number of the month.

So what you need is:

```
std::cout << 1900 + nowTm->tm_year
   << "/" << 1 + nowTm->tm_mon
   << "/" << nowTm->tm_mday;
```

Comment: Thanks! :) And once again thanks to everyone who commented - just my careless mishap that generated that extra 0 T_T

Comment: @CodeApprentice NP :) I think you also missed a ‘1’ in the comments, I doubt you divided by 0, hah.